# Domain name resolution tool not specific to DNS

Tags: dns, nsswitch

`host`, `dig` and `nslookup` can be used to lookup DNS names from the command line. However, they query the names from the DNS server directly, instead of using `nsswitch` to resolve host names. This means /etc/hosts and mDNS aren't used.

Is there a command line tool that looks up the name by the standard way (honouring mDNS and /etc/hosts)?

There is a [similar question on Ask DIfferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70579/what-is-the-preferred-method-of-command-line-domain-name-lookup-dns), but it seems to be specific to OS X.

Comment: You just need any utility that goes through nsswitch, their `ping` answer there would work for you as well.

Comment: It's true that I can just use `ping`. But it feels like "overkill" to use ping just to find an IP address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getent` to query various DBs including hosts.

`$ getent hosts <hostname>`

If your server has a V6 address but you want a V4 address, you may need to use the ahostsv4 DB instead.

`$ getent ahostsv4 www.google.com`

As an additional tool, you could try calling `gethostbyname()` in a program.  C would be fine, but here is a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Socket;

my $ip = gethostbyname($ARGV[0]); 
if (defined $ip) {
  my $ip_addr = inet_ntoa($ip);
  print "$ip_addr\n";
}
```

If a host on the command line has only a single IP, it will be printed below.

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for. This, for example, doesn't work for mDNS.

Comment: @Kritzefitz This is exactly what you're looking for: it's the same resolution code that applications use, based on NSS (unlike `hosts`, `dig` and `nslookup` which are specific to DNS). It should work with mDNS.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work for mDNS"?  You're saying you don't get an address that you would get with "ping"?  I'll add in a perl lookup script that should do the same thing to the answer.  Try that as well.

Comment: @bowlofred `gethostbyname()` does not produce the same result because it is a backward compatibility interface that only works for IPv4. `getaddrinfo()` is what you want to use here.

Comment: Sorry. I've mistaken the use of getent. I looked at it again and it works. Sorry for saying it doesn't work.